# Ignore files when publishing packages for Deno

Tags: configuration-files, deno

I have done [my first package](https://github.com/UltiRequiem/fibonacci-deno) for [Deno](https://deno.land), and then I publish it to [deno.land/x/](https://deno.land/x/fina@v0.2.0).

I would like to know if there is a way to Ignore some files and dires at the time of upload the package, example: [".github",".vim","test_deps.ts"].

Pretty much like [.npmignore](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/using-npm/developers#keeping-files-out-of-your-package).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is not currently a way to ignore files, but if you'd like to only include certain files, you can organize them separately in a subdirectory of your repository, and use that option when [publishing your module](https://deno.land/x#info):

[image: deno - publish module - options - subdirectory]

The subdirectory that you choose in this step will become the root of the module's file hierarchy.